# Replacement for HLOOKUP formula to find most recent entry with additional criteria in unsorted data?

Tags: excel, sorting, lookup

I need to find a formula to replace the current HLOOKUP in the "Individual Report" tab under the "Recurring" column (F5:F92) to identify the MAX Date in the "Recurring" Assessment Type per "SENTRI ID" and return those values.

The data is NOT pre-sorted by date, so it's returning the first "Recurring" value not necessarily the MAX "Recurring" value.

Excel sheet with dummy data: [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EbTJgQQJWk6kz96iNgJmagm1hElHA4VB/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103680776446027899246&rtpof=true&sd=true)

------------------------------------------

I added a Pivot Table to find the MAX value per ID, then tried to update the string in F3, but perhaps because it became one long string of numbers versus "###Recurring", it doesn't return anything...?

**ETA:  Using =XLOOKUP(MAXIFS(CANS_Date,SENTRI_ID,$B$2),CANS_Date,CANS_Date,"")
will return the MAX date, but not the MAX "Recurring" Date.

I'm not sure what formula to use to return the text-based values (i.e. Staff Name, Consumer Name, Assessment Type).**

------------------------------------------
Additional notes:

- There are too many items to use a form for entry (88)
- The staff who enter the data are NOT tech savvy enough to change their default enter-to-down to enter-to-right

Here are the potential alternative solutions I've thought through but am hoping I will not have to resort to:

1. Resort the data manually and then every time new data is entered
2. Add an additional "Assessment" type called "Most Recent" and update previously entered data as needed manually every time new data is entered
3. Rebuild the "Data" tab to enter by row and not column and face the wrath of the staff for the increased entry time

Comment: Have you considered index() with match()? the lookup value being found with max().

Comment: I have (and I'm sure this is likely the fault of my formula) but I get #spill or #n/a errors no matter what I've tried. The spill errors were related to the data spilling in the row versus in the column.  The latest iteration was #/na error: "=INDEX(MATCH(MAX(Data!D6:S6),$B$2=Data!D4:S4)*Data!D6:S6,6)"

Comment: where is the array that index will use? Like "=INDEX(D6:S6,MATCH("etc

Comment: =INDEX(Data!D6:S6,MATCH(MAX(Data!D6:S6),$B$2=Data!D4:S4),6)

Comment: So you just added what I did as an example? Have you tested it? If it does not work then you need to test each part separately to see the result that it gives and work out what will happen next compared to what you expect.

Comment: =INDEX(MATCH(MAXIFS(CANS_Date,SENTRI_ID,$B$2),CANS_Date,CANS_Date),,) returns the wrong date

=XLOOKUP(MAXIFS(CANS_Date,SENTRI_ID,$B$2),CANS_Date,CANS_Date,"") returns the correct date.  I guess now I just need to update the other cells in this column

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, this is what I ended up doing:
For the MAX date in F9, I'm rolling with the MAX and not just the MAX of "Recurring".  It's not ideal but it'll work.

```
=XLOOKUP(MAXIFS(CANS_Date,SENTRI_ID,$B$2),CANS_Date,CANS_Date,"")
```

For cells F10:F92, I used FILTER to grab the right scores:

```
=FILTER(Data!D7:ZZ7,(Data!$D$4:$ZZ$4='Individual Report'!$B$2)*(Data!$D$6:$ZZ$6='Individual Report'!$F$9),"missing")
```